# Crop and center image to circle in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image, geometry

can you help me to crop rectangle image to circle, a crop to center? I need adjust width of cropped image to column width.

My code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle" src="http://wallpaper.pickywallpapers.com/1920x1080/mark-wahlberg-front-profile.jpg" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="col-8">Hello there!</div>
</div>
```

My solution not works, and made from my image ellipse. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's solution for this using 1x1 aspect ratio set via pseudo-element padding which calculation is based on parent's width. you can find detailed articles below

JS is used for calculating image aspect ratio.

```
if width/height == 1 - image is square
if width/height > 1 - image is wide
if width/height < 1 - image is narrow
```

after calculation `tallAndNarrow` class applied if needed and `loaded` class added for all images to show with opacity fade in and no shakes during tall image reposition

> Height equals width with pure CSS http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html
>
> Maintain Aspect Ratio SASS Mixin https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/maintain-aspect-ratio-mixin/

```js
function fixAspect(img) {
  var $img = $(img),
    width = $img.width(),
    height = $img.height(),
    tallAndNarrow = width / height < 1;
  if (tallAndNarrow) {
    $img.addClass('tallAndNarrow');
  }
  $img.addClass('loaded');
}
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}

.circle:before {
  display: block;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 100%;
}

.circle>img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX( -50%);
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .4s;
}

.circle>img.tallAndNarrow {
  width: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateX(0) translateY( -50%);
  left: 0;
  height: auto;
}

.circle>img.loaded {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-4">
  <div class='circle'>
    <img src="http://wallpaper.pickywallpapers.com/1920x1080/mark-wahlberg-front-profile.jpg" alt="" onload='fixAspect(this);'>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="col-4">

  <div class='circle'>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x350" alt="" onload='fixAspect(this);'>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-4">

  <div class='circle'>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" onload='fixAspect(this);'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @DenisStephanov keep in mind that current solution assumes you have image which has $width > $height, might need some CSS/JS tweaks in case if your api will have another type of images (square, tall and narrow).

Comment: Yes you right, so it does not solve my problem, images from API has variable dimensions, also squares :/

Comment: @DenisStephanov okay, updated. works fine for all cases. image is centered vertically/horizontally

Answer (score 2):

In hope it helps someone:
If you don't need it to be a `<img>` (your only purpose is to show the image anyhow), you could replace the `<img>` by a `<div>` and set the image source as the background-image for that `<div>`.

This will give you more options to achieve what the OP wants, using less code (in fact, it's a pure and simple CSS matter):

```css
.cover-image {
  /* src image (replaced original since it's not available anymore) */
  background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/1920x1080);
  
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: center;
  
  /* desired height */
  height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="rounded-circle cover-image">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8">Hello there!</div>
</div>
```

It's possible to do a lot more, since resizing and positioning a `<div>` is fairly easy, and using the `background-size: cover` CSS will always maintain the aspect ratio of the image used on the background while resizing it to fill all available space with minimum resizing (and cropping the rest).

Answer (score 1):

Are you just trying to make a square image into a circle with css? Your question is a little confusing. Using `.border-radius` can make it into a circle using CSS.

Css to use:

```
<style type="text/css">
  .rounded-circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

And then your html would be.

```
<div class="col-4">
    <img class="img-fluid rounded-circle" src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: I receive images from API, so I have to work with rectangles, not squares.